# Elegant way to Identify columns based on regex and fill different default values

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe which can be generated from the code below

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'person_id' :[1,2,3],'date1':['12/31/2007','11/25/2009',np.nan],
           'hero_id':[2,4,np.nan],'date2':['12/31/2017',np.nan,'10/06/2015'],
           'heroine_id':[1,np.nan,5],'date3':['12/31/2027','11/25/2029',np.nan],
           'bud_source_value':[1250000,250000,np.nan],
           'prod__source_value':[10000,20000,np.nan]})
```

The dataframe looks like as shown below with Nan's

[image]

What I would like to do is

1) Fill na's with 0 (zeroes) for columns that ends with "id"
2) Fill na's with "unknown" for columns that ends with "value"
3) Fill na's with "12/31/9999" for columns that starts with "date"

I tried the below approach but it's lengthy and feel it isn't elegant

```
df2 = df.filter(regex='id$')
df2.fillna(0)

df2 = df.filter(regex='^date')
df2.fillna('12/31/9999')

df2 = df.filter(regex='value$')
df2.fillna('unknown')
```

Is there anyway to achieve this in one go? As you can see I am kind of repeating the same steps

Comment: however, the maintainability and readability are also quite important. If there would be say 7 patterns of interest,  I woulfn't treat a potential lengthy one-liners as elegant

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For multiple choices according to multiple conditions you can use [`np.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html):

```
import numpy as np

# choices
c = df.columns.str
c1 = c.endswith('id')
c2 = c.endswith('value')
c3 = c.startswith('date')

out = np.select([c1,c2,c3], [df.fillna(0), df.fillna('unknown'), df.fillna("12/31/9999")])
pd.DataFrame(out, columns=df.columns)

    person_id   date1     hero_id  date2       heroine_id  date3  \
0         1  12/31/2007       2  12/31/2017          1  12/31/2027   
1         2  11/25/2009       4  12/31/9999          0  11/25/2029   
2         3  12/31/9999       0  10/06/2015          5  12/31/9999   

      bud_source_value prod__source_value  
0         1.25e+06              10000  
1           250000              20000  
2          unknown            unknown
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`DataFrame.fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) with dictionary as:

```
d = {col:value for col_s,value in zip(['id','value','date'], [0,'unknown','12/31/9999']) for col in df.filter(like=col_s)}

df = df.fillna(d)

print(df)
   person_id       date1  hero_id       date2  heroine_id       date3  \
0          1  12/31/2007      2.0  12/31/2017         1.0  12/31/2027   
1          2  11/25/2009      4.0  12/31/9999         0.0  11/25/2029   
2          3  12/31/9999      0.0  10/06/2015         5.0  12/31/9999   

  bud_source_value prod__source_value  
0         1.25e+06              10000  
1           250000              20000  
2          unknown            unknown  

print(d)
{'person_id': 0,
 'hero_id': 0,
 'heroine_id': 0,
 'bud_source_value': 'unknown',
 'prod__source_value': 'unknown',
 'date1': '12/31/9999',
 'date2': '12/31/9999',
 'date3': '12/31/9999'}
```

Comment: Does this your regex check whether chars like "id", "value" and "date" are just present in the column names. Does it check whether it is at the beginning or end?

Comment: @AVLES It checks only whether the key word present or not.